# How do you explain *(y_ptr)&val;

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-address, dereference

### Problem description

I the following example I wrote the `*x_ptr = *(y_ptr)&val;` I can't understand why the output is `10`. What happened in the memory? I can't understand this combination.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
   int *x_ptr, *y_ptr;
   int val = 10;
   y_ptr = &val; 
   *x_ptr = *(y_ptr)&val;
   
   std::cout << *x_ptr << std::endl;
}
```

---

Suppose that I change `*x_ptr = *(y_ptr)&val` to `x_ptr = *(y_ptr)&val` the compiler will give the following error why?

```
10:20: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]
```

Comment: This is undefined behavior: dereferencing uninitialized `x_ptr`.

Comment: `&` is the binary AND operator.

Comment: Oh my, I can see the confusion. It's being interpreted as `(*(y_ptr))&(val)`, but if `y_ptr` was a type instead of a variable it would also make sense as `*((y_ptr)(&val))`

Comment: sorry @Mark Ransom. You go it. I really wanted to reach what you meant in your comment. I drowned in my own stupidity. Can you give an example on : **but if y_ptr was a type instead of a variable it would also make sense as *((y_ptr)(&val))**

Comment: The ampersand `&` has *two* meanings, it can either be a bit-wise `and` or it can be taking the address of a variable as a pointer. The parentheses `()` also have two meanings, they can mean operator grouping or they can mean C-style type casting. It is context that determines which meaning is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output is `10` because any number bit-AND-ed with itself stays unchanged.

What the expression does is simple: it dereferences `y_ptr`, which points to `val`, and bitwise-ANDs the result with the same `val`.

**Note:** you need to initialize `x_ptr` to some location to avoid a potential crash from dereferencing an uninitialized pointer.

Answer (score 2):

It's a really awkwardly spaced and parenthesized way of doing bitwise `&`. More clearly:

```
*x_ptr = *y_ptr & val;
```

Though `x_ptr` is uninitialized, so this is UB anyway.

Your edited code is an error because you're trying to assign an `int` to an `int*`, as your compiler explicitly states. This is clearly invalid.